# Transarent background over heavyweight components

Tags: java, swing, transparent, jlayeredpane

I've got a problem. In LayeredPane I have 2 components: heavyweight coponent and JComponent(or any other what I could draw text in) that is placed above the first one. I'd like JComponent to have transparent background, but it has black background. Heavyweight coponent is a component that renders video and JComponent is component what I draw text in. This text should be printed with transparent background.

I tried to use GlassPane but glass content of glassPane was displayed above lightweight components and below heavyweight component.

Is there possibility to draw text above heavyweight coponent (Canvas)?

ps. I can't overload paint method because I got object of class HeavyComponent that is subclass of Canvas.

Comment: Do you really need `HeavyComponent`? why not extend from `JPanel` instead?

Comment: Moreover, "a heavyweight [component] is always opaque."—http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/mixing/

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.java-forums.org/awt-swing/29372-transarent-background-over-heavyweight-components.html and http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5440791&tstart=0

Comment: I have to use HeavyComponent because I get this component from getVisualComponent() method of JMF package

Answer (score 0):

A heavyweight component will generally paint over lightweight components.

JMF is quite old. Investigate some of the newer alternatives. See the section labeled "Alternatives" at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Media_Framework